# Using Plink to run a command

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I am trying to create a script to login to a remote server and run a command.  The script is as follows

```
plink.exe UserName@ServerIP -pw PASSWORD -batch -m PATHTOFILEWITHSCRIPT.txt
```

PATHTOFILEWITHSCRIPT.txt has this line

```
debug software restart process user-id
```

The script when run logs into the server but does not run the command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Martin.  For others looking for the answer this is the format that you need

echo COMMAND | plink.exe UserName@ServerIP -pw PASSWORD -batch -ssh

Answer (score -1):

The format that is required is

```
echo COMMAND | plink.exe USER@SERVER -pwd PASSWORD -batch
```

where COMMAND is the command that you want to run after you log in

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers. Accept that your question is duplicate. And if the linked question and its answer has helped you, please consider upvoting them.

Comment: Duplicated question + answer